# Knockout data-binding enable only for desktop/laptop

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to KO and getting my head around data binding.

I have a button that is only clickable when the user has a valid email. I am using 'enable' on the data-bind attribute to make sure it's clickable/unclickable. Unfortunately on mobile we can't see the icon/tool-tip to show why it's not clickable. Is there anyway to make data-binds, or the enable attr to be specific to what kind of device you are using?
HTML below.

```
<button class="button" data-bind="click: $parent.send, enable: userHasEmail">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible (there are libraries such as Bowser that you could utilize), but a much simpler solution would be to use CSS media queries and display the error message only on mobile devices.

Something like this:

```
<div class="error-message mobile-only" data-bind="hidden: userHasEmail">
    <!-- error message here -->
</div>
```

And then hide it for laptops/desktops like so:

```
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
    .mobile-only {
        display: none;
    }
}
```